# Left join twice on same table with multiple ids

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

How can I join twice on 1 table, and join it 2 different columns from another table.

```
SELECT table1.id_a, table2.INFO AS Data_1, table1.id_b, table2.INFO AS Data_2
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table2.id_a = table1.id_a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table2.id_a = table1.id_b;
```

Data1 col should show the info corresponding to the id_a
and 
Data2 col should show the info corresponding to the id_b

```
TABLE 1
--------
ID_A        ID_B
------------------
A           X
B           Y
C           Z

TABLE 2
--------
ID_A        INFO
-----------------
A           apple
B           pear
C           orange
Y           watermelon
X           banana
Z           blueberry




Expected output
--------------
ID_A        Data1          ID_B           Data2
-----------------------------------------------
A           apple          X               watermelon
B           pear           Y                banana
C           orange         Z                blueberry
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious to me if your query will achieve what you want without more info, but I'm certain your current issue is a lack of aliases.  Alias each table so you can reference each one explicitly:

```
SELECT t1.id_a, t2a.INFO AS Data_1, t1.id_b, t2b.INFO AS Data_2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2a ON t2a.id_a = t1.id_a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2b ON t2b.id_a = t1.id_b;
```

EDIT: To demonstrate fully:

```
with tab1 as (
    select 'A' id_a, 'X' id_b from dual
    union all
    select 'B' id_a, 'Y' id_b from dual
    union all
    select 'C' id_a, 'Z' id_b from dual)
  , tab2 as (
     SELECT 'A' id_a, 'apple' info from dual
    union all
     SELECT 'B' id_a, 'pear' info from dual
    union all
     SELECT 'C' id_a, 'orange' info from dual
    union all
     SELECT 'X' id_a, 'watermelon' info from dual
    union all
     SELECT 'Y' id_a, 'banana' info from dual
    union all
     SELECT 'Z' id_a, 'blueberry' info from dual
    )    
select  t1.id_a, t2.info, t1.id_b, t3.info
from   tab1 t1
left outer join tab2 t2 on t2.id_a = t1.id_a
left outer join tab2 t3 on t3.id_a = t1.id_b;

ID_A INFO  ID_B   INFO_1
A    apple    X   watermelon
B    pear     Y   banana
C    orange   Z   blueberry
```

Comment: Tried with an alias and no dice

Comment: @user9959589 Could you add a couple rows of sample data, the updated query with aliases, and your expected results to your question?  Without table aliases, your current select won't know which `table2` you are referencing.  Beyond that it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @user9959589 this code does what you expect. If you can't make it work then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @user9959589 You may need to update your sample data.  As shown in the edit, this works with the current sample set.  Make sure you use the correct aliases with the correct columns in your joins and select.  Here is a sql fiddle version http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28485/1/0